# Visual Studio Code opens multiple terminals while running electron

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

How do I prevent Visual Studio Code to show mulitple terminals while running electron application.

When I'm running it using visual studio it looks like:

[image]

It looks like it is using it to do some form of interprocess communication but is it possible to hide those terminals?

While using only `npm start` those terminals doesn't show up.

Comment: If you solved the problem you should put the solution in an answer and later accept it so people know it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `--enable-logging` in launch.json causing it. Remove that and terminals won't appear.